# Adding a specific Button to the bottom of a scrolling PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, button, view, footer, preferenceactivity

I was having errors implementing this using by trying to add a button that utilized xml code for the buttons display information. I got past this by creating a single button, adding it to the footer, and setting the id to that of the ok_button ID in my R file.

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.buttons);

        /* Add Button to the Bottom of List */
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("OK");
        button.setId(R.id.ok_button);
        ListView v = getListView();
        v.addFooterView(button);
    }
}
```

This works!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following steps:-

1. Create a XML layout which contains a ListView (you must have it) and the buttons that you want to add at the bottom.
2. Add your layout using setContentView(R.layout.your_layout) method after addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings) method.

3.You can access the buttons as you do normally.

Update:-

Your layout code should be like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#00000000">
    </ListView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The ListView must have the id **@android:id/list**. You can use RelativeLayout if you need.

Comment: Thank you for my response. Could you check my update? I may have done it wrong, but I tried your implementation and got the same error.

Comment: I changed from LinearLayout to ListView, and set the content view directly after addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings); Still no luck.

Comment: Check my updated answer, You should not add the button as child of the ListView.

Comment: I changed my buttons.xml layout xml file to exactly what you have above, and tried you implement everything else the way I have listed above, still no luck.

Comment: Remove this part ListView v = getListView();
            View okButtonView = findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
            v.addFooterView(new Button(this));

Comment: Now it loads the screen, but no button at the bottom :/

Comment: I figured it out, answer is in the edited question. +1 for helping

Comment: how to do this on a PreferenceFragmentCompat ?